# Patch Request to API in Angular 6 Updating only the Last Item in Object Array

Tags: angular, typescript, api, request, patch

I have a football team with player names and details. I open a model in order to edit the player's details.

When I set new data which then fires a patch request, the data seems to edit the last item in the object array and not the specific item I am editing.

I have a really rudimentary setup in my component, whereby the patch gets sent from there instead of my service, but for now, I just need to see it work. I can set this up properly later on.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

**I have a feeling it might be the loop?**

```
getHomeTeam(): void {
this.HometeamService.getHomeTeam().subscribe(hometeam => {
  this.hometeam = hometeam;
    for (let i =0; i < hometeam.length; i++) {
     this.player_id = hometeam[i].id;
    }
  });
}
```

**Update**

So the fix was pretty simple, thanks to @robert's help, I needed to pass hometeam.id into the patch request instead of this.player_id

```
updatePlayer(hometeam) {
let player_id = hometeam.id;
this.http.patch('https://sidelineapp.io/demo/api/1.1/tables/home_team/rows/' + hometeam.id, hometeam).subscribe(status => {
  console.log(hometeam.id);
  this.getHomeTeam();
  this.ngxSmartModalService.close('playerModal');
});
```

}

The modal data is rendering correctly, so pretty sure it isn't in the view, but happy to share the form if this might be the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the for loop you update the same this.player_id hometeam.length times. Looks a bit strange.

Comment: @robert yes, that's what I thought, I've tried foreach, but this logs out the entire object and passes the object as player_id to the request URL, which just fires back a 500 error with [object object]

Comment: Sure, but I need more code and data. For instance what you have in "hometeam" array? Also can you share the whole component.

Comment: sure, will edit the question. What I am attempting to do here is to define the hometeam.id as player_id so it can be successfully passed into the request URL.

Comment: I suspect that is the reason for this: "data seems to edit the last item in the object array and not the specific item I am editing." In the loop you set the player_id always to the last item in the array.

Comment: @robert - took a while, but here is my component and data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189739/discussion-between-robert-and-apex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two changes:

Remove this for loop:

```
for (let i =0; i < hometeam.length; i++) {
     this.player_id = hometeam[i].id;
}
```

And instead of this.player_id use hometeam.id like this:

```
updatePlayer(hometeam) { this.http.patch('https:some_url/' + this.hometeam.id, hometeam)
```